# getting correct click coords with ggplot map in shiny

Tags: r, user-interface, ggplot2, click, shiny

I have the start of a shiny app with a ggplot map of the world. I would like to get the coordinates of the click on the plot so users can do things with the map, but the coordinates are very strange (either `NULL` or something very small). Clicking repeatedly only seems to change one coordinate:

[image: complex map]

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  # Application title
  headerPanel("My App"),
  sidebarPanel(
    textOutput("clickcoord")
  ),

  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("myworld", height="600px", clickId="plotclick")
  )
))
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
library(ggplot2)
library(rworldmap)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$myworld <- renderPlot({

     world <- map_data("world")
     worldmap <- ggplot(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), data = world) +
       geom_path()

    print(worldmap)
  })

  output$clickcoord <- renderPrint({
          print(input$plotclick)
  })
})
```

If I just use the `map()` command to generate a non-ggplot world map, I get what looks like good lat/long values for the click coords:

[image: simple map]

server.R (modified):

```
library(shiny)
library(maps)
library(mapdata)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$myworld <- renderPlot({
      map("world2Hires")
    })

    output$clickcoord <- renderPrint({
      print(input$plotclick) 
    })

})
```

Comment: AFAIK, shiny does not support plot-locationing for ggplot2 (or more generally grid graphics).

Comment: I've tried running this code and first discovered that there are missing right curley-brace and right-paren in the server.R file. After adding those I am now seeing `ERROR: argument "metaHandler" is missing, with no default` in a FireFox web tab. The examples run fine in the shiny tutorial I am following, so I don't think I have missing basic components.

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixed the missing delimiters. I double-checked the example, and it worked okay. Do you have the latest Shiny (0.8 iirc)?

Comment: In an example I tried in a different setting, the x-y coordinates were in a 0-1-square, so perhaps one could scale them appropriately...

Comment: @user1965813 Hopefully there is some projection information there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replace `print(worldmap)` with `worldmap` in your original code you will get what you want. Shiny works perfectly fine with ggplot2. The function `print()` seems generate a figure whose x and y are reset in the range (0, 1).